# Ionic 2 - Sidemenu change after user Login

Tags: ionic2, side-menu

I want to change my sidemenu after a user login so I can display the name and its sidemenu. I think this code is understandable.

```
rootPage: any = SlidesPage;    
    if( SlidesPage){
              this.pages = [
                { title: 'Welcome', component: SlidesPage },
                { title: 'Home', component: HomePage },
                { title: 'House & Lot', component: HousePage },
                { title: 'Condominium', component: CondoPage },
                { title: 'Apartment', component: ApartmentPage },
                { title: 'Hotel', component: HotelPage }
              ];
            } else {
              this.pages = [
                { title: 'Dashboard', component: SellerPage },
                { title: 'My Properties', component: SellerPage },
                { title: 'Properties', component: HomePage },
                { title: 'House & Lot', component: HousePage },
                { title: 'Condominium', component: CondoPage },
                { title: 'Apartment', component: ApartmentPage },
                { title: 'Hotel', component: HotelPage }
              ];
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

set a token in localstorage when you login

`this.storage.set('vAuthToken', vAuthToken);`

then check it on intializaApp() in app.component.ts

```
 initializeApp() {
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.storage.get('vAuthToken').then((val) => {
    if (val == null) {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false, 'authenticated');
    this.menuCtrl.enable(true, 'unauthenticated');
  }
  else {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(true, 'authenticated');
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false, 'unauthenticated');
  }
  });
 });
 }
 this.authenticated = [
            { title: 'Welcome', component: SlidesPage },
            { title: 'Home', component: HomePage },
            { title: 'House & Lot', component: HousePage },
            { title: 'Condominium', component: CondoPage },
            { title: 'Apartment', component: ApartmentPage },
            { title: 'Hotel', component: HotelPage }
          ];
          this.unauthenticated = [
            { title: 'Dashboard', component: SellerPage },
            { title: 'My Properties', component: SellerPage },
            { title: 'Properties', component: HomePage },
            { title: 'House & Lot', component: HousePage },
            { title: 'Condominium', component: CondoPage },
            { title: 'Apartment', component: ApartmentPage },
            { title: 'Hotel', component: HotelPage }
          ];
```

Hope this will helpful to you !

Comment: ok ty, I will try this when I will be working on functionalities for now Im working with the UI.

Answer (score 0):

The ionic conference app shows exactly how to do this, using the Event-system, local token storage and arrays with pages. Also along the lines of Jaydeep Kataria's code.

Just start a new project, with the ionic conference template (latest ionic version of course)

Regards,

Tom